# Python/Tkinter IntVar not updating Label

Tags: tkinter

Help!

I've created a simple GUI mimicking a set top box. All of the functions are working except one.

I want the label that displays the 'channel' to default back to 1 when inputs are changed from 'TV' to 'Radio'.

The IntVar associated with the label is self.chan_value. I tried to set the radiobuttons option command = self.chan_value.set(1), but still nothing happens when I press the radiobuttons.

Using self.chan_value.set(1) seems to work fine when invoked by the function connected to the channel entry box, but I've had no luck getting the radiobuttons to work.

I've tried defining a method like:

```
def chan_resetter(self):   
     self.chan_value.set(1)
```

But this really doesn't seem that different from just setting the command.
Here's my code. The problem is in the 'input frame' section, with the two radiobuttons tv_rb and radio_rb

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox


class MySetTopBox:


    def __init__(self):


        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        # frames
        self.power_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.input_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        # (channel frames)
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        self.volume_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.quit_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)



        # channel frame

        # top frame
        self.desc_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, text='CHANNEL:')
        self.chan_value = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.chan_value.set(1)
        self.chan_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, textvariable = self.chan_value)        

        self.desc_label.pack(side='left')
        self.chan_label.pack(side='left')

        # mid frame
        self.change_button = tkinter.Button(self.mid_frame, text='Change Channel', command= self.channel_function)
        self.chan_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.mid_frame, width = 10)

        self.chan_entry.pack(side='left') 
        self.change_button.pack(side='left')



        # input frame 

        chan_resetter = self.chan_value.set(1)

        self.input_var = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.input_var.set(1)

        self.input_label = tkinter.Label(self.input_frame, text='INPUT')
        self.tv_rb = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.input_frame, text='TV', variable=self.input_var, value = 1, command= chan_resetter, indicatoron=0, width=5, padx=20)
        self.radio_rb = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.input_frame, text='RADIO', variable=self.input_var, value = 2, command= chan_resetter, indicatoron=0, width=5, padx=20)

        self.input_label.pack()
        self.tv_rb.pack(side='left')
        self.radio_rb.pack(side='left')



        # volume frame
        self.volume_var = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.volume_var.set(5)

        self.volume_label = tkinter.Label(self.volume_frame, text='VOLUME')
        self.volume_scale = tkinter.Scale(self.volume_frame, from_=0, to_=10, variable=self.volume_var)

        self.volume_label.pack(side='top')
        self.volume_scale.pack(side='left')        



        # quit frame

        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.quit_frame, text='Quit', command= self.main_window.destroy)
        self.quit_button.pack(side='left') 

        self.power_var = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.power_var.set(2)



        # power frame
        self.casey_label = tkinter.Label(self.power_frame, text="Casey's Set Top Box")
        self.power_label = tkinter.Label(self.power_frame, text='POWER')
        self.on_rb = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.power_frame, text='ON', variable=self.power_var, value=1,command=self.default_function())
        self.off_rb = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.power_frame, text='OFF', variable=self.power_var, value=2)

        self.casey_label.pack(side='top')
        self.power_label.pack()
        self.on_rb.pack(side='left')
        self.off_rb.pack(side='left')      



        # pack frames

        self.power_frame.pack()
        self.input_frame.pack()
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.volume_frame.pack()
        self.quit_frame.pack()


        tkinter.mainloop()



    def default_function(self):
        self.input_var.set(1)
        self.chan_value.set(1)
        self.volume_var.set(5)     
        #include messagebox? 'you have turned the power off'



    def channel_function(self):
        new_chan = int(self.chan_entry.get())
        input_current = self.input_var.get()
        power_off = self.power_var.get()
        if power_off ==2:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error', 'Turn Set Top Box power ON first') 

        elif input_current == 1 and new_chan > 30:
            tv_error = 'ERROR: TV channels range from 1 to 30'
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error', tv_error)

        elif input_current == 2 and new_chan > 12:
            radio_error = 'ERROR: Radio channels range from 1 to 12'
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Error', radio_error)

        else:
            self.chan_value.set(new_chan)


    def volume_function(self):
        vol_entered = self.volume_var.get()
        self.volume_var.set(vol_entered) 



my_stb = MySetTopBox()

print (my_stb.input_var.get())
print (my_stb.chan_value.get())
print (my_stb.volume_var.get())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `lambda` function

```
command=lambda:self.chan_value.set(1)
```

.

```
self.tv_rb = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.input_frame, text='TV', variable=self.input_var, value = 1, command=lambda:self.chan_value.set(1), indicatoron=0, width=5, padx=20)
```

or create function `chat_resetter` in this way

```
def chan_resetter():
   self.chan_value.set(1)

self.tv_rb = tkinter.Radiobutton(self.input_frame, text='TV', variable=self.input_var, value = 1, command=chan_resetter, indicatoron=0, width=5, padx=20)
```

`chan_resetter` has to be inside `__init__` as other instructions (the same indentions) - it is not another function in class `MySetTopBox` but part of `__init__`

---

But you can alwasy define `chan_resetter` as another function in class `MySetTopBox`

```
def chan_resetter(self):
   self.chan_value.set(1)
```

and then use `lambda` to call it

```
command=lambda:chan_resetter(self)
```

---

```
chan_resetter = self.chan_value.set(1)
```

Code above means - set `chan_value` to `1` and result assign to `chan_resetter` but `self.chan_value.set(1)` as result give `None` so you get `chan_resetter = None`

```
command=self.chan_value.set(1)
```

Code above means the same - run `self.chan_value.set(1)` and result assign to `command` so you get `command=None`

Comment: The lambda function worked! However defining chan_setter inside of the __init__ function did not work.