# IntVar not updating between function Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, widget

**PROBLEM: IntVar doesn't update**

I am trying to create a window that displays 3 frames with 9 checkbutton to choose 1 checkbutton per frame to change color map of visualization of an image, this is a small part of the big code I am typing.
here is my code for changing color bands:

```
class Inicio(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...

#Cambiar_banda_de_colores

    def cambio_banda(self):

        cambio = tk.Tk()
        cambio.wm_title("Cambio de bandas del Landsat")
        top_frame = tk.Frame(cambio, bg='white', bd=2, relief=tk.SUNKEN)
        top_frame.pack(side=tk.TOP ,fill="both", expand=True)
        ttk.Label(top_frame, text="Escoja 3 bandas para visualizacion en orden (RGB) ").pack(side=tk.TOP )

     #Frame 1
        box1 = tk.LabelFrame(top_frame, text="Primera Banda ", bg='red', width=110, height= 250,  bd=3, relief=tk.RAISED)
        box1.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill="both")

    #Frame 2
        box2 = tk.LabelFrame(top_frame, text="Segunda Banda ", bg='green', width=110, height= 250,  bd=3, relief=tk.RAISED)
        box2.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill="both")

    #Frame 3
        box3 = tk.LabelFrame(top_frame, text="Tercera Banda ", bg='blue', width=110, height= 250,  bd=3, relief=tk.RAISED)
        box3.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill="both")

    #my 3 IntVar
        ssbanda1 = tk.IntVar()
        ssbanda2 = tk.IntVar()
        ssbanda3 = tk.IntVar()

    #an inside funtion just to print
        def cambiar():

            print "Bandas seleccionadas"
            print "banda1: ", ssbanda1.get(), ", banda2: ", self.ssbanda2.get(), ", banda3: ", self.ssbanda3.get()


#To optimize code I am creating the checkbutton like this:
        lista = range(1, 10, 1)
        lista2 = ['Banda Costera', 'Banda Azul', 'Banda Verde', 'Banda Rojo', 'Banda NIR', 'Banda SWIR 1',
              'Banda SWIR 2', 'Banda Pancromatica', 'Banda Cirrus']

        for l1, l2 in zip(lista, lista2, ):
            a = tk.Checkbutton(box1, text="{0} ({1})".format(l2, l1), onvalue=l1, variable=ssbanda1)
            a.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

    #repeat 2 more times for `ssbanda2` and `ssbanda3`

    #button to call `cambiar` func to print
        boton1 = tk.Button(top_frame, text="Aceptar", command= cambiar)
        boton1.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

        cambio.mainloop()
```

but when I print I got `ssbanda1=0`

previously I have created the long way like this:

```
    a1 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w", text="(1)Banda Costera",         variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(1), onvalue=1).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    a2 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w",text="(2)Banda Azul",             variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(2), onvalue=2).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    a3 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w",text="(3)Banda Verde",            variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(3), onvalue=3).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    a4 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w",text="(4)Banda Rojo",             variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(4), onvalue=4).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    a5 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w",text="(5)Banda NIR",              variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(5), onvalue=5).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    a6 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w", text="(6)Banda SWIR 1",          variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(6), onvalue=6).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    a7 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w",text="(7)Banda SWIR 2",           variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(7), onvalue=7).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    a8 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w",text="(8)Banda Pancromatica",     variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(8), onvalue=8).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
    a9 = tk.Checkbutton(box1, anchor= "w",text="(9)Banda Cirrus",           variable=ssbanda1, command= lambda: ssbanda1.set(9), onvalue=9).pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
```

But can't do that using the `lambda` because it will overwrite each time `ssbanda1` on the loop and always print `ssbanda1=9`

Have tried running the loop in a separate script and worked perfect but on my program doesn't, had already checked  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966554/python-tkinter-intvar-not-updating-label?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244047/why-cant-i-set-my-intvar?noredirect=1&lq=1).
Do I have to use `self` expression? `global` variables? use the `cambiar` function outside?

This is the window:

[image]

**TL;DR:** I am trying to optimize 9 lines into 1 loop but IntVar doesn't update in callback function of button

Comment: Is there a reason you are using checkbuttons instead of Radiobuttons? A Radiobutton is designed to only have one selected out of a group.

Comment: Mmm I already tried with radiobutton as you said but with checkbutton in my code I can only choose one as radiobutton also. I don't like in radiobutton  when screen load the buttons are as preselected (in gray) and then when pressing one option it goes all deselected.

Comment: I just did the suggestion of Bryan Oakley and the thing I said about being preselected dissappear, I think will change to Radiobuttons now, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating more than once instance of `Tk`. Each has its own private namespace, and the widgets and variables in one can't be shared by another.

If you need more than one window, create instances of `Toplevel` rather than multiple instances of `Tk`.

This may not be the only problem, but it's such a large problem that there's no point in investigating any further until it is resolved.

Comment: Just did that and solved the problem, thanks a lot :)